# Computing Value of n

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, algebra, relational-algebra

I am working to compute the value of n for the following equations:-

1. n! = 10^7
   (For this computation what i've done so far is n(n-1)! = 10^7 . But how should i proceed further. I have no idea)
2. n^n = 10^9 (For this i tried to take logs on both sides. But the answers are not satisfactory)

Help me out in these computations for the value of n.
I want my answer should be computed in terms of Logs or Powers etc..

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about maths, not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try all n, starting from 2 upwards.  You will find for 1.):

```
10! = 3628800 < 10^7 < 11! = 39916800   -> 10<n<11
```

and for 2.):

```
9^9 = 387420489 < 10^9 < 10^10 -> 9<n<10
```

The precise result for 2 is

```
n=9.295
```

as computed by [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) .

Comment: I want my answer should be computed in terms of Logs or Powers etc.. And not in form or points as u mentioned in 2nd case i.e. n=9.292..

Comment: There is no closed form for this.  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%5En+%3D+10%5E9) tells you everything about this problem.

Comment: Welcome to the real world :-)  You better get used to the idea that most equations cannot be solved, only in very rare, exceptional cases you will be able to solve an equation analytically.

Comment: In addition, the factorial equation has no solution, unless you generalize to the Gamma function.